# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "stehe zu" und "stehe hinter"?

Tags: difference, german-to-english

I would like to inquire about the difference in meaning if I want to translate these two sentence into English:

- > Ich stehe zu dir
- > Ich stehe hinter dir

Could both sentences mean "I'm standing with you"? Or do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both German sentences can (and often will) be used with the meaning of supporting someone (I've never heard the English *I'm standing with you*, so I'm not 100% sure if this is the correct translation).
They are not exactly the same, both can have other meanings as well.
*Ich stehe hinter dir* can also be meant in the literal way as "I'm standing behind you".
*Ich stehe zu dir* can also be used when another person (probably when you are not around) tells me that you are not good for me but I say that I'm not going to end our friendship because of that person's advice.

Comment: Many thanks Volker landgraf for your specified answer,

Comment: Sorry I'm new on this site,, I have just upvoted the answer,

Comment: You need 15 reputation to upvote (and 125 to downvote, currently you have 11), so you can't upvote the answer until you gain another 4 (e.g. by someone else giving your question an upvote). What you can do *additionally* is marking one answer to your question as the accepted answer by clicking the hook below the arrows.

Comment: Good answer. You may add one more detail: "Ich stehe zu Dir" means: I belong to you. Nobody can separate us (as you said in your example). "Ich stehe hinter Dir" is more of the meaning "whatever decision you take: I will support you". This is just a slight difference, as one is for the person him/herself and the other is about decisions of the person.

Answer (score 3):

Although @Volker Landgraf did a good job explaining the difference with these terms I feel like there are a few suttle things that can be added here.

*"Ich stehe zu dir"* is more often than not used to imply a positive relation between the parties, like friends or intimate partners, meaning something like *"I will be there at your side however bad your decisions may be"*.

*"Ich stehe hinter dir"* often implies a leading role of the addressed person. If A says to B *"Ich stehe hinter dir"*, then A is saying that B does something and A has a supporting role in that matter. This phrase is often used when talking politics, for example when you are talking about the support of a political party for the idea proposed by a specific politician.   *"Die Partei steht geschlossen hinter dieser Entscheidung"* *"The party as a whole supports that decision."*

I hope this explaination further improved the distinction between those two phrases.

Comment: your explanation did make the difference more comprehensible now,